# Amazon Checkout in Facebook Page

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, amazon-product-api

I have integrated Checkout by Amazon(CBA) in my application. It working fine in outside the Facebook. In Facebook, it blocking the Amazon login popup window.

[image]

When i use to click 'Pay with Amazon' button, it should ask for Amazon login in pop-up window but there is no response. Is there any issue with  Facebook iframe? Please help me.
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you inspected the console output

Comment: I checked it already but it seems to blank!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon payments won't work in Facebook iframe. That the message i got from Amazon support.